# Render Table not working in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am not able to use `renderTable`. This is the error I am getting:

> Error in UseMethod("xtable") : no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character"

Also, I want the final output to be just 2 columns

1. Concatenate 2-4 columns
2. Column 5

---

```
#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  content_data <- renderTable({

    ga$getData(id, start.date="2015-10-01", end.date=Sys.Date()-1,
               metrics = "ga:pageViews",
               dimensions = "ga:date, ga:day, ga:month, ga:year",
               sort = "ga:date",
               filter =  paste0("ga:pagePath=@/tp", input$text))[,2:5]
  }) 
  output$table1 <- renderTable(content_data())
})

#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  textInput("text", label = h3("City"), value = "Enter city name..."),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(12, tableOutput("table1")))

))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactive Table Not Showing up in Shiny](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34127605/reactive-table-not-showing-up-in-shiny)

Comment: If you are understanding the problem..Could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `renderTable` within `renderTable`. Try with this server function:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderTable({  
      ga$getData(id, start.date="2015-10-01", end.date=Sys.Date()-1,
               metrics = "ga:pageViews",
               dimensions = "ga:date, ga:day, ga:month, ga:year",
               sort = "ga:date",
               filter =  paste0("ga:pagePath=@/tp", input$text))[,2:5]
  })        
})
```

For the concatenation, you have to process the data before `renderTable`. Something like this should work (next time please post reproducible example).

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

content_data <- reactive({
  df<-ga$getData(id, start.date="2015-10-01", end.date=Sys.Date()-1,
             metrics = "ga:pageViews",
             dimensions = "ga:date, ga:day, ga:month, ga:year",
             sort = "ga:date")[,2:5]
  #return concatenated 2-4 and 5
  cbind(paste(df[2],df[3],df[4]),df[5])
 })

output$table1 <- renderTable(content_data)
})
```

Comment: How can I add chart on my UI basis table1. I want to create output$plot1 but I am not neither able to use content_data nor tabel1.

Comment: You should be able to create the plot with `renderPlot()` and `content_data()[1]` or `content_data()[2].`

Comment: My bad. try with this. `output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({plot(content_data()[,1], content_data()[,2])})`